# Get INSERT string on JDBC

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I’m trying to write a method to get the string from the SQL INSERT query to the DB, with an input array as the number of columns using JDBC:

```
public String methodtest(String ListofColumns)
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO" + TableName + "(" + ListOfColumns + ")";
    try
    {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        While (rs.next())
        {
            String result = rs.getString(query);
            System.out.println("The SQL query is " + result);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlEx)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        rs.close();
    }
}
```

Can you see any mistake?

*Thanks, Monkawee, for the advice.*

Comment: Start with [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).

Comment: For an "insert or update" functionality, look at the `MERGE` statement: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: @MarkMcDowell, your question originally showed no effort to solve it, no clue about what you do and don’t know, basically it was just asking for a tutorial, which is off-topic here. You should have edited it to show what you have. You did so (wrongly) in an answer, so I edited your question for you and now we have at least some code to begin with. So now, *what’s the question?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern:

```
public string methodtest(Array listofcolumns)
{
    try{
        <Connection string path>
        <DB connection method>
        <Query string>
        <Execution>
        <Reset Object>
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlEx){
        // handle exception
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        // handle other exceptions if any
    }
    finally{
        <Close connection and other resources like PreparedStatement>
    }
}
```